# Wheel rolling leaned against a vertical wall

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rigid-body-dynamics, stability

I'm new with rigid problems about. I'm trying to solve this:

> A massive circular disk of mass m, radius R, and negligible thickness is leaned against a
>   vertical wall, slanting by 45 . In the gravitational field, it can oscillate, rolling without
>   slip on the ground and along the wall.

[image]

I need to write down the equations of motion of the disk.

I try to use the [Euler's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_equations_(rigid_body_dynamics)). Since there's no torque, $I_1=I_2 \neq I_3 $, and $ \omega_1=\omega_2=0$ ($\omega_2$ is the desired angular speed)
Therefore $$I_2\dot\omega_2=0 \Rightarrow \omega=kte$$

But this is not useful because obviously the motion is an oscillatory one.

How to write the equation of motion of this?

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

*I don't want that you solve this for me. I want to understand how to get the equations.*

Comment: But there _is_ a torque - what does the normal force do as the disk rocks back and forth?

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't realize that. Can it be written as $Rd\theta mg\cos\phi $? ($\phi$ is the inclination of the disk)

Comment: It might be easier to just do this from the Lagrangian. The rotational KE in both the $\theta$ and $\phi$ directions is simple to write down, and the gravitational potential depends only on the height of the center of mass, which can be easily converted to a function of $\phi$.

Comment: You might want to put a bounty on this question. It is interesting and complicated at once.

Comment: @probably_someone Would it be possible to solve this with normal high school level physics, like F = ma net torque = Ialpha, I don't know about stuff like euler angles or lagrangian (yet) Can you write an answer for it?